# Unable to decode stream: FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, image, bitmap, camera

In my database I have for every entry one uri to a picture on my mobile phone. To display it on the phone, there is a CustomAdapter for the Listview. Now, I want to display the picture in the ListView and get the following error message:

```
05-13 12:20:34.234: E/BitmapFactory(17684): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/10139: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
BitmapDrawable: cannot decode external/images/media/10139
```

It happens at this function:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderEreignis holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_ereignis, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolderEreignis((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.enullline), (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.efirstLine), (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eimgv));

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolderEreignis) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Ereignis ki = (Ereignis) getItem(position);
    holder.getEreignisname().setText(ki.getEreignisname());
    holder.getEreignisdatum().setText(ki.getEreignisZeit());
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(ki.getEreignisbild());
    BitmapDrawable b = new BitmapDrawable(ki.getEreignisbild());

    System.out.println("ÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜÜ" + uri.getPath());
    holder.getEreignisbild().setImageDrawable(b);

    return convertView;

}
```

Like you see, I output the URI of the image that looks like this:

```
external/images/media/10139
```

Does someone know this error?

**EDIT:**
Here is the code where I add the image:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String TITLE = null;
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, TITLE);
    String DESCRIPTION  = null;
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, DESCRIPTION);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
     imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    System.out.println("VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVvv" + imageUri.getPath());
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

**EDIT2:**

Here is the code how I add the link to the database:

```
public void insertereignis(String ename, String ezeit, String egenaueres, String ebild, int kindid){
        long rowId = -1;
        try{    
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();


            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            System.out.println(ename + ezeit + egenaueres);
            cv.put(EREIGNISNAME, ename);
            cv.put(EREIGNISZEIT, ezeit);
            cv.put(EREIGNISGENAUERES, egenaueres);
            cv.put(EREIGNISBILD, ebild);
            System.out.println("GRIAISDALSDJLASJDLKASJDKLAJSDLKJFS" + ebild);
            cv.put(KINDID, kindid);

            rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_EREIGNIS, null, cv);           
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "insert() Ereignis", e);
        }
        finally{
            Log.d(TAG, "insert(): Ereignis rowId=" + rowId);
        }
    }
```

the value of ebild is `/external/images/media/10146`

Comment: don't you need the file extension? Like `10139.jpg` or something?

Comment: I tried that but no, I don´t need it

Comment: then I think it is something with the image path. It clearly says that there is no such file. Where is your image located?

Comment: The image is shown in the gallery.

Comment: ok, but where in your memory is this image located, on your sdcard or somewhere else?

Comment: I can not say that exact, I added the code where I add the image

Comment: you must check if a file with that path really exists. The error says that the file does not exist, so first thing you have to try is to see if it exists or not

Comment: I checked it now. Also tried to take the picture path that is shown in the gallery in picture info. no success.

Comment: can you tell me the image path that is shown in the gallery?

Comment: it is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1368438768752.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Don't you see the problem? You have many solutions.

1. Change `ebild` to have value in format `/DCIM/Camera/filename.jpg` and then use imgeUri like this:

   ```
   imageUri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + uri.toString();
   ```
2. Change `ebild` to have value in format `filename.jpg` and then use imgeUri like this:

   ```
   imageUri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/" + uri.toString();
   ```
3. Assign the whole image path to `ebild` like:

   ```
   ebild = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/" + "filename.jpg"
   ```

   and then use it as image uri without any modification.

I don't know what else to say. The solution is obvious.

**EDIT:**

Here is how you can set the file name as timestamp:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String cameraImageFileName = "IMG_" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" +
               ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 < 10) ? ("0" + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)) : (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)) + "-" +
               ((c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < 10) ? ("0" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) : c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "_" +
               ((c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 10) ? ("0" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) : c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + "-" +
               ((c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 10) ? ("0" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) : c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + "-" +
               ((c.get(Calendar.SECOND) < 10) ? ("0" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND)) : c.get(Calendar.SECOND)) + ".jpg";
```

You will get the filename in format `IMG_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.jpg`

and your `imageUri` would be:

```
imageUri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + cameraImageFileName;
```

and you should add this as `ebild` in your database:

insertereignis(ename, ezeit, egenaueres, **imageUri**, kindid);

Comment: no, there must be a different problem. I added a hardcoded file path and it is not shown too!

Comment: what harcoded path did you add? where did you add it? try this: `BitmapDrawable b = new BitmapDrawable(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/" + "filename.jpg");` where filename.jpg is name of some existing image

Comment: I added this: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1368438768752.jpg

Comment: when you crate the intent for capturing the image, the `imageUri` is the location of the file where the image will be saved after taking it with the camera. If you want to use the third solution what you should do is you have to insert the `imageUri` in your database as `ebild`. `ebild = imageUri`. And for the filename you can use some kind of timestamp. See the answer for the filename as timestamp